# Как с помощью for, и метода slice реализовать переворот строки. Переместить символ с 0 индекса в конец строки

Tags: javascript

Последовательно переставляет все символы в строке из нулевого индекса на последний,
Например, для слова 'robot':

Первый шаг: берем первую букву (r) слова 'robot' и переставляем ее в конец слова - 'obotr';

Второй шаг: берем первую букву (о) слова 'obotr' и переставляем ее в конец – 'botro' и так далее.

```js
function scrollingText(word) {
  let upperCase = word.toUpperCase()
  resArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < upperCase.length; i++) {
    resArray.push(upperCase[i]);
    console.log('Original', resArray);
    let newLetterArray = resArray.slice(1)
    console.log('New', newLetterArray)
  }
  return 'final result' + ' ' + resArray
}
let res = scrollingText('Tymoha');
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Не совсем, тут только первую букву перекидывает в конец строки, а нужно что бы каждую последущую.

Answer (score 0):

Так сойдет?

```js
function scrollingText(word) {
  newLetterArray = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    newLetterArray += word.slice(word.length - i - 1, word.length - i);
  }
  return newLetterArray;  
}
let res = scrollingText('Tymoha');

console.log(res);
```